# WP Rocket Cache Lifespan - Never clear cache?

Tags: cache

Recently I've installed WP Rocket. Works good but even if the cache lifespan option is set to 10 hours it actually never really clear the cache and caching files are growing each day. When I clear cache manually, from Dashboard, it works, but it is never cleared by cron, as it should.

I've tried to find logs, errors, permissions problem but I do not see any of these.

Is there something I missed, some settings, PHP extension, or anything that I have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange! Unfortunately, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more. A better place to ask this type of question may be [The Official WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/) or the [plugin specific support](https://wp-rocket.me/support/).